# MATLAB eig vs eigs vs svd vs svds

Tags: matlab

I'm running an MCMC scheme, in which I calculate a lot of eigenvalues. The matrices will have between around 10x10 to 200x200, so not massive, and deifnitely not at the size where I would need to consider using sparse matrices.

Each matrix I'm looking at has a 0 eigenvalue, and I just need to find the eigenvector corresponding to that 0 eigenvalue. Which function out of eig, eigs, svd, svds would be fastest for this?

eigs allows you to specify that you only want the smallest eigenvalue (or nth smallest eigenvalues), so instinctively I'd think this would be faster - though  don't know anything about the underlying methods. I think similar can be done for svd/ svds.

I've also run into issues with the methods (except for eigs) telling me that my system is almost singular, whihc doesn't occur when I use eig.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the best method to use would be?

Comment: test them for speed ;) If you have 0 eigenvalues, then your system is singular

Comment: [How to calculate the eigenvector corresponding to zero eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28773/how-to-calculate-the-eigenvector-corresponding-to-zero-eigenvalue).